# SSH access to GoDaddy hosting from MacOS terminal

Tags: macos, ssh

Attempting to access my GoDaddy hosting account via ssh from MacOS terminal.

Using "ssh cpanellogin@hostname" (which uses the default port 22) I receive the error: "Unable to negotiate with xxx.xxx.xx.xxx port 22: no matching host key type found. Their offer: ssh-rsa,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss" where xxx.xxx.xx.xxx is the correct IP address of my host.

Keys were generated by cPanel SSH Access utility which placed them in the ~/.ssh subdirectory of the GoDaddy host. I downloaded keys to the ~/.ssh subdirectory of my Mac (client). In creating the keys a key password was set up. I am able to sftp access with these keys using FileZilla.

How to fix ssh access?

Tried "ssh cpanellogin@hostname". Expecting access, or at least a key password prompt.

Comment: Browsing various sites over the last few days I found the solution. I knew it would be simple, and it was: ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa login@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, where xxx... is the IP address. The default ssh port 22 is used so no need to include. the -o parameter tells the host (GoDaddy) the key algorithm used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the SSH -o parameter to indicate the key algorithm required between client and host. So in MacOS terminal on the client:
ssh -oHostKeyAlgorithms=+ssh-rsa login@xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
where xxx... is the host IP address. The default ssh port 22 is used so no need to include. A config file is offered to record this key algorithm requirement so you do not have to include it every time in the command. Of course this is noted in the man pages for ssh, but those pages are long and difficult for many to unravel...
See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/836048/ssh-returns-no-matching-host-key-type-found-their-offer-ssh-dss